# Get handle of the running instance of an app

Tags: c++, windows, instance

In my program I'm checking if an instance of the app is already running using mutex.

Now I would like to know how I could get an handle on the already running instance of the app to bring it to front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FindWindow to get the handle of the window and the SetWindowPos to bring it to the front.

Comment: Yeah bu the Window name can change depending on many parameters that the other instance hasn't ...

Comment: That is true. If you know the window class will be unique the you can use FindWindow(szClassName, NULL) to match all window names.

Comment: I managed to make it work! The main problem was that I didn't know the name of the class! I used a tool to determine it and then it's working well! (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34981/FindWindow)